# How to fix configure error in QEMU?

Tags: linux, qemu

I'm facing an issue with configuring QEMU for generating traces.
This is how my config.log looks like:

```
# Configured with: '/home/aananya/qemu-8.0.0/configure' '--target-list=x86_64-softmmu' '--meson=/home/aananya/.local/bin/meson' '--ninja=/home/aananya/.local/bin/ninja' '--enable-kvm' '--prefix=/usr' '--enable-trace-backends=simple' '--disable-werror' '--disable-auth-pam'

#
cc -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -c -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -c -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o config-temp/qemu-conf.c
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:2:2: error: #error _i386_ not defined
    2 | #error _i386_ not defined
      |  ^~~
cc -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -c -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -c -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o config-temp/qemu-conf.c
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:2:2: error: #error _ILP32_ not defined
    2 | #error _ILP32_ not defined
      |  ^~~
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -c -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Werror -Wundef -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wundef -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Werror -Wwrite-strings -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wwrite-strings -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror -Wredundant-decls -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wredundant-decls -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Werror -Wold-style-declaration -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wold-style-declaration -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Werror -Wold-style-definition -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wold-style-definition -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Werror -Wtype-limits -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wtype-limits -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Werror -Wformat-security -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wformat-security -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Werror -Wformat-y2k -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wformat-y2k -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Werror -Winit-self -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Winit-self -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Werror -Wignored-qualifiers -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wignored-qualifiers -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Werror -Wempty-body -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wempty-body -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Werror -Wnested-externs -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wnested-externs -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Werror -Wendif-labels -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wendif-labels -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Werror -Wexpansion-to-defined -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wexpansion-to-defined -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Werror -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Werror -Wmissing-format-attribute -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wmissing-format-attribute -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Werror -Wthread-safety -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wthread-safety’
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wthread-safety -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wthread-safety’
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Werror -Winitializer-overrides -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Winitializer-overrides’
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Winitializer-overrides -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Winitializer-overrides’
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Werror -Wmissing-include-dirs -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wmissing-include-dirs -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Werror -Wshift-negative-value -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wshift-negative-value -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wno-shift-negative-value -Werror -Wstring-plus-int -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wstring-plus-int’
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wstring-plus-int -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wstring-plus-int’
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wno-shift-negative-value -Werror -Wtypedef-redefinition -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wtypedef-redefinition’
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wtypedef-redefinition -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wtypedef-redefinition’
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wno-shift-negative-value -Werror -Wtautological-type-limit-compare -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wtautological-type-limit-compare’; did you mean ‘-Wtautological-compare’?
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wtautological-type-limit-compare -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wtautological-type-limit-compare’; did you mean ‘-Wtautological-compare’?
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wno-shift-negative-value -Werror -Wpsabi -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wpsabi -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1obj’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-psabi -Werror -Wgnu-variable-sized-type-not-at-end -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wgnu-variable-sized-type-not-at-end’
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Werror -Wgnu-variable-sized-type-not-at-end -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.m
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wgnu-variable-sized-type-not-at-end’
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-psabi -Werror -fstack-protector-strong -c -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-psabi -Werror -fstack-protector-strong -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -mcx16 -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-psabi -fstack-protector-strong -Werror -fPIE -DPIE -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -fstack-protector-strong -pie
cc -m64 -mcx16 -fPIE -DPIE -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-psabi -fstack-protector-strong -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -pie -fstack-protector-strong
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:2:3: error: #error LITTLE
    2 | # error LITTLE
      |   ^~~
cc -m64 -mcx16 -fPIE -DPIE -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-psabi -fstack-protector-strong -pthread -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -pie -fstack-protector-strong -lgmodule-2.0 -pthread -lglib-2.0
cc -m64 -mcx16 -fPIE -DPIE -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-psabi -fstack-protector-strong -pthread -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -Werror -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -pie -fstack-protector-strong -lgmodule-2.0 -pthread -lglib-2.0
cc -m64 -mcx16 -fPIE -DPIE -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-psabi -fstack-protector-strong -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -pie -fstack-protector-strong
cc -m64 -mcx16 -fPIE -DPIE -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-psabi -fstack-protector-strong -Werror -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -pie -fstack-protector-strong
cc -m64 -mcx16 -fPIE -DPIE -std=gnu11 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-psabi -fstack-protector-strong -Werror -c -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m32 -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o -c config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m32 -r -nostdlib -o config-temp/qemu-conf2.o config-temp/qemu-conf.o -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
cc -m64 -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o -c config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -r -nostdlib -o config-temp/qemu-conf2.o config-temp/qemu-conf.o -lgcc
```

This is what I'm running on the terminal:
`./configure --target-list=x86_64-softmmu --meson=/home/aananya/.local/bin/meson --ninja=/home/aananya/.local/bin/ninja --enable-kvm --prefix=/usr --enable-trace-backends=simple --disable-werror --disable-auth-pam`

Can someone suggest what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be failing with something about ***cc1obj*** which is the **Objective C compiler**.

Try installing gobjc++ and then try again:

```
sudo apt-get install gobjc++
```